# Proving a subspace of $C(X\times Y)$ is dense in $C(X\times Y)$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $X,Y$ are compact, show that the subspace of $C(X\times Y)$, spanned by the functions of the form $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$, for $g\in C(X),h\in C(X)$ is dense in $C(X\times Y)$.

Not sure where to start on this one, so I'll just point out some stuff I know.
First off, $C(X)$ is the space of all continuous functions $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$, but since $X$ is compact we can extend this to say that it is the space of uniformly continuous functions $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$. I think since $X$ and $Y$ are compact, then $X\times Y$ is compact as well, so $C(X\times Y)$ will be all uniformly continuous functions $g:X\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$. If those functions span the subspace, then that means some linear combination of those functions "equals" the subspace. To show that the subspace is dense in $C(X\times Y)$, its closure must be equal to $C(X\times Y).$

Perhaps something along these lines would work:

Since $X\times Y$ is compact, and $R$ is a subalgebra of $C(X\times Y)$ (?), and $R$ separates points and vanishes at no point in $C(X\times Y)$, then $R$ is dense in $C(X\times Y)$ by Stone-Weierstrass. (where $R$ is our subspace)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $C(X)$ has a topology given by uniform norm? If $C(X)$ has a topology given by uniform norm and $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff, you can apply Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Yes it has the uniform norm $||f||_{\infty}:=\sup_{x\in X}|f|$

Comment: @tetori: My apologies, but what is meaning of "Hausdorff"?

Comment: You should probably say why your subalgebra separates points and vanishes at no point. See if you can find functions for which those properties are true for. (not necessarily the same function of course)

Comment: @Mikael A topological space $X$ is Hausdorff if every two different points in $X$ can be separated by for some disjoint neighborhoods; that is, for each $x,y\in X$, $x\neq y$ there are disjiont open sets $U$, $V$ such that $x\in U$, $y\in V$ and $U\cap V$ is empty.